# React Native: Console Warning Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0): TypeError: Cannot read property 'uri' of null

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase, react-native-image-picker

I am following this tutorial on uploading photos to Firebase in React Native and have it all set up using 'react-native-image-picker' and 'launchImageLibrary' (instead of the 'showImagePicker' in the tutorial as it is no longer in use). However, when I click the 'Upload Image' button, I get this error/warning:

[image: Console Warning]

My UploadScreen.js file is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

export default function UploadScreen() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0);

  const selectImage = () => {
    const options = {
      maxWidth: 2000,
      maxHeight: 2000,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images'
      }
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };
        console.log(source);
        setImage(source);
      }
    });
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const { uri } = image;
    const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
    setUploading(true);
    setTransferred(0);
    const task = storage()
      .ref(filename)
      .putFile(uploadUri);
    // set progress state
    task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
      setTransferred(
        Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
      );
    });
    try {
      await task;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    setUploading(false);
    Alert.alert(
      'Photo uploaded!',
      'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
    );
    setImage(null);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.selectButton} onPress={selectImage}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Pick an image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        {image !== null ? (
          <Image source={{ uri: image.uri }} style={styles.imageBox} />
        ) : null}
        {uploading ? (
          <View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
            <Progress.Bar progress={transferred} width={300} />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.uploadButton} onPress={uploadImage}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload image</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#bbded6'
  },
  selectButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  selectButton2: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  uploadButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ffb6b9',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 50,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  progressBarContainer: {
    marginTop: 20
  },
  imageBox: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

What is causing this warning and how can I fix it?

#### Attempted fixes

1. AFTAB

```
const selectImage = () => {
    const options = {
      maxWidth: 2000,
      maxHeight: 2000,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images'
      }
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const  uri = image?.uri;
        console.log(source);
        setImage(response);
      }
    });
  };
```

Result:

[image: Console Warning]

2. RAHMAN

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

export default function UploadScreen() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0);

  const selectImage = () => {
    const options = {
      maxWidth: 2000,
      maxHeight: 2000,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images'
      }
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response?.uri };
        console.log(source);
        setImage(source);
      }
    });
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const { uri } = image;
    const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
    setUploading(true);
    setTransferred(0);
    const task = storage()
      .ref(filename)
      .putFile(uploadUri);
    // set progress state
    task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
      setTransferred(
        Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
      );
    });
    try {
      await task;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    setUploading(false);
    Alert.alert(
      'Photo uploaded!',
      'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
    );
    setImage("");
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.selectButton} onPress={selectImage}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Pick an image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        {image !== "" && image !== undefined && (
          <Image source={{ uri: image?.uri }} style={styles.imageBox} />
        )}
        {uploading ? (
          <View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
            <Progress.Bar progress={transferred} width={300} />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.uploadButton} onPress={uploadImage}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload image</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#bbded6'
  },
  selectButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  selectButton2: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#8ac6d1',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  uploadButton: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ffb6b9',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 50,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  progressBarContainer: {
    marginTop: 20
  },
  imageBox: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  }
});
```

Result:

[image]

Console error after updating the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue here:

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response?.uri };
        console.log(source);
        setImage(source);
      }
    });
```

You have to set an image as this:

```
setImage(response);
```

And then you can get it like this:

```
 const  uri = image?.uri;
```

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes and I'm now getting a different warning. I have edited the question to show the changes I made and then the new warning screen :/

Answer (score 0):

The warning is showing because the URI is null. Make sure you have getting URL response properly and try this code.

```
export default function UploadScreen() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0);

  const selectImage = () => {
    const options = {
      maxWidth: 2000,
      maxHeight: 2000,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images'
      }
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response?.uri };
        console.log(source);
        setImage(source);
      }
    });
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const { uri } = image;
    if (uri) {
      const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
     setUploading(true);
     setTransferred(0);
     const task = storage()
       .ref(filename)
       .putFile(uploadUri);
     // set progress state
     task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
      setTransferred(
        Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
      );
    });
   }
    try {
      await task;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    setUploading(false);
    Alert.alert(
      'Photo uploaded!',
      'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
    );
    setImage("");
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.selectButton} onPress={selectImage}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Pick an image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        {image !== "" && image !== undefined && (
          <Image source={{ uri: image?.uri }} style={styles.imageBox} />
        )}
        {uploading ? (
          <View style={styles.progressBarContainer}>
            <Progress.Bar progress={transferred} width={300} />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.uploadButton} onPress={uploadImage}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload image</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I made these changes and am now getting a different error/warning. I have edited the question to show the changes I made and then the new error :/

Comment: can you console filename and uri you passing because its seems uri is getting undefined and also please refer the new answer, If you still get the error please comment

Comment: Ah okay so with your edited code I now get the alert for 'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!' however I also get an error 'ReferenceError: task is not defined'... I will show a screenshot in the bottom of the question

Comment: Its because u r not getting a valid url. can you make sure you are getting a valid uri and its going inside of that if statement

Comment: How would I make sure I'm getting a valid uri?

Comment: Add a console.log and check in ur metro bundler

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what metro bundler is?

Comment: you can see your logs on terminal..I think you are already running a debugger you can see the console logs on their

Comment: I'm going to make a new question as I feel this has progressed past the original problem